# Как написать логику рендеринга событий в календаре событий

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пишу календарь событий на vue и бьюсь уже три дня над попыткой придумать логику рендеринга событий недельного календаря таким образом, что бы события реагировали на положение других событий того же дня, и изменяли свою ширину дабы не перекрывать собой остальных.
Пример того, что требуется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: Так чего желаешь в ответах: чтобы тебе придумали логику изменения размеров, или чтобы перечислили способы реализации? Проблема вопроса пока не ясна.

Comment: Не рассчитываю, что кто то за меня придумает реализацию, но это было бы идеальным вариантом, а так ожидаю идеи способов реализация / примеры похожих работ с открытым исходным кодом / возможно библиотеки которые помогут это реализовать, если таковы существуют. Все что по твоему, или другого человека, мнению может мне как то помочь прийти к пониманию того, как решить задачу.

Comment: Теперь понятнее. Тут явно придется использовать абсолютное позиционирование как для контейнеров (если синие элементы на картинке ими являются), так и для элементов событий; И те и другие сделать компонентами; Элементы событий ограничивать по ширине, считая лимит в computed свойстве, как частное от деления ширины контейнера (переданной через пропсы) на макс. кол-во стоящих "рядом" событий в нем (определить это перекрытие будет проще по времени событий, чем по координатам их элементов). Что касается координат элементов для бинда в `style` - в их вычислении поможет метод `getBoundingClientRect`.

Comment: @yar85 но как определять граничащие события?

Comment: Выражением вида `(eventA.from <= eventB.to) && (eventA.to >= eventB.from)`, если я логику не напутал в своей сонной башке. Это проверка на пересечение диапазонов... таким сравнением в цикле ищем максимальную длину цепочки пересечений, затем делим ширину контейнера на полученное число. Результат будет шириной элемента события (чтобы уместить рядом). Кстати, для сравнения, значения времени надо привести к числовым... так как сравниваться будут значения времени внутри одного дня - сойдет приведение к количеству минут с полуночи (split строки, затем часы * 60 + минуты).

Comment: @yar85 Спасибо.